# In Java, how do I print something if only 2 out of 3 values are 1, 2 or 3?

Tags: java, if-statement, conditional-statements

This is for an exercise that plays with the idea of cards, so it asks me to print "SIX" if only 2 out of 3 cards are 1, 2 or 3. This is my code now but if I were to input, say, 1 2 and 3 it would still return "SIX" even though there are more than 2 values of 1 2 or 3:

```
       if (card1 == 1 || card1 == 2 || card1 == 3 && card2 == 1 ||card2 == 2 || card2 == 3 && card3 > 3) {
            System.out.println("SIX");
        }
        else if (card1 == 1 || card1 == 2 || card1 == 3 && card3 == 1 ||card3 == 2 || card3 == 3 && card2 > 3) {
            System.out.println("SIX");
        }
        else if (card2 == 1 || card2 == 2 || card2 == 3 && card1 == 1 ||card1 == 2 || card1 == 3 && card3 > 3) {
            System.out.println("SIX");
        }
        else if (card2 == 1 || card2 == 2 || card2 == 3 && card3 == 1 ||card3 == 2 || card3 == 3 && card1 > 3) {
            System.out.println("SIX");
        }
        else if (card3 == 1 || card3 == 2 || card3 == 3 && card2 == 1 ||card2 == 2 || card2 == 3 && card1 > 3) {
            System.out.println("SIX");
        }
        else if (card3 == 1 || card3 == 2 || card3 == 3 && card1 == 1 ||card1 == 2 || card1 == 3 && card2 > 3) {
            System.out.println("SIX");
        }
```

Just starting to get into coding so any help would be nice. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

First, your conditions are wrong, because `&&` has higher precedence than `||`, which means that the following two statements are the same:

```java
if (card1 == 1 || card1 == 2 || card1 == 3 && card2 == 1 ||card2 == 2 || card2 == 3 && card3 > 3) {
if (card1 == 1 || card1 == 2 || (card1 == 3 && card2 == 1) ||card2 == 2 || (card2 == 3 && card3 > 3)) {
```

What you meant was:

```java
if ((card1 == 1 || card1 == 2 || card1 == 3) && (card2 == 1 ||card2 == 2 || card2 == 3) && card3 > 3) {
```

Second, for something like this, it's better to go with a counter, to simplify the code:

```java
int count = 0;
if (card1 == 1 || card1 == 2 || card1 == 3) {
    count++;
}
if (card2 == 1 || card2 == 2 || card2 == 3) {
    count++;
}
if (card3 == 1 || card3 == 2 || card3 == 3) {
    count++;
}
if (count == 2) {
    System.out.println("SIX");
}
```

Using the `? :` ternary operator, that can be further simplified:

```java
int count = (card1 == 1 || card1 == 2 || card1 == 3 ? 1 : 0)
          + (card2 == 1 || card2 == 2 || card2 == 3 ? 1 : 0)
          + (card3 == 1 || card3 == 2 || card3 == 3 ? 1 : 0);
if (count == 2) {
    System.out.println("SIX");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can let the collections library do the heavy lifting:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(card1);
list.add(card2);
list.add(card3);
list.removeIf(i -> i >= 1 && i <= 3);
if (list.size() == 1) {
    System.out.println("SIX");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it using only conditionals. There are many other ways too.

- First check that at least 1 card is > 3. This is done by inverting (!) the condition if all three cards are less than or equal to 3.
- Then check that only two of the remaining cards are <= 3

```
if (!(card1 <= 3 && card2 <= 3 && card3 <= 3)) {
    // Now check that only two of the remaining cards are <= 3
    if ((card1 > 3 && card2 <= 3 && card3 <= 3)
            || (card2 > 3 && card1 <= 3 && card3 <= 3)
            || (card3 > 3 && card1 <= 3 && card2 <= 3)) {
        System.out.println("SIX");
    }
}
```

You could also simply stream the cards and filter them.

- only let cards of value `<= 3` thru the filter.
- then count them.
- if there are two cards, print SIX

```
if (IntStream.of(card1,card2,card3).filter(card->card <= 3).count() == 2) {
            System.out.println("SIX");
}
```

For more help on conditionals I recommend you check out [De Morgan's Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)